# Visual Studio 2015 Change the Default Values of the Configuration Properties

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I need to change the default settings of the TargetServerVersion. 
It is currently 'SQL Server 2016 or later', and I would like to change this to 'SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012, or 2014' as the default so I do not have to change this each time I create a new report.